# bash: redirected file seen by script as 'does not exist '

Tags: bash

I want to check if there are any errors with the last command, hence redirecting stderr to a file and checking the file for "error" string.(Only one possible error in this case.)

My script looks like below:

```
 #aquire lock

 rm -f /some/path/err.out
 MyProgramme 2>/some/path/err.out &

 if grep -i "error" /some/path/err.out ; then
    echo "ERROR while running MyProgramme, check /some/path/err.out for error(s)"
    #release lock          
    exit 1
 fi
```

'if' condition is giving error 'No such file or directory' on err.out, however I can see the file exists.

Did I miss anything ?.. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

PS: I couldn't check the exit code using $? as it is running in background.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the file possibly not existing when you call `grep`, you only call `grep` once, and it only sees whatever data is currently in the file. `grep` will not continue reading from the file when it reaches the end, waiting for `MyProgramme` to complete. Instead, I would recommend using a named pipe as the input to `grep`. This will cause `grep` to continue reading from the pipe until `MyProgramme` does, in fact, complete.

```
#aquire lock

rm -f /some/path/err.out
p=/some/path/err.out
mkfifo "$p"
MyProgramme 2> "$p" &


if grep -i "error" "$p" ; then
   echo "ERROR while running MyProgramme, check /some/path/err.out for error(s)"
   #release lock          
   exit
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

When you start `MyProgramme` in the background, it's possible that `grep` executes *before* `MyProgramme` could write (and thus create) to the file `/some/path/err.out`. That's why even though the file exists later when you check it yourself, `grep` couldn't find it.

You can wait until the background job completes using `wait` before inspecting the file using `grep`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The program here runs never ends. Any other way than waiting ?

Comment: Hmm I might be wrong but I thought that `>` results in the file being created/truncated immediately?

Comment: @Srikanth If the program never ends then how do you know at what point it prints "error"? How long you do want to wait? Do you want to immediately exit the script if the "err" file doesn't exist? I mean if the program runs forever or for a long time then shouldn't be checking if errors out at the end or at least regularly.

Comment: I wanted to check if there is any error in starting the program, like cannot open a shared library..

Comment: @TomFenech it does.

Comment: @TomFenech @TomFenech File's truncated *before* the program is run - that's true. But the program may not be immediately scheduled by the shell. I tried to verify it with: `#!/bin/bash
;
rm test ;
sleep 1 > test & ;
cat test ;` (place newlines in place of `;`) and then running it with `for ((i=0;i<100;i++)); do ./s; sleep 0.1; done 2>&1 | grep -c No`. I don't always get 100 as output.

Comment: @TomFenech Ignore my loop. Just consider my script. If `sleep` line were to create `test` file everytime *before* `cat` gets executed then there won't be any "No such file .." error from the `cat` command.

Comment: @123 @TomFenech The calling shell, upon seeing `&`, first forks a subshell to process the pipeline. The child shell is the one that creates the file before starting `MyProgramme`, and may not be scheduled before `grep` runs.

Comment: @123 If the downvote is yours, I'd like to know what's wrong.